# JavaScript считает undefidnded элемент из json

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, cookie

Получаю успешно от сервера json такого типа:

```
{'200': ' kh>lxsvh8k'}
```

Когда я пытаюсь вот здесь :

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
        const authResponse = await fetch(`/auth/${login.value}/${password.value}`);
        const authResult = await authResponse.json();

        console.log(authResult);
        
        if (authResult[0] == "403") {
          status.style.color = "red";
          status.innerHTML = "Этот ник занят";
        }
        else {
          // setCookie функция для установки куки
          setCookie("session", authResult[0], 666);
          window.location.replace("/");
        }
```

у меня в при просмотре установленного куки-файла значение пишется как undefinded. Можете объяснить в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> у меня в при просмотре установленного куки-файла значение пишется как undefinded. Можете объяснить в чём ошибка?

Давай посмотрим (см.комментарии в коде)... Думаю что все очевидно.

```js
// это ты получил...
const authResult = {200: ' kh>lxsvh8k'}
// это ты записал...
console.log(authResult[0])
```